# How do I create a "write once" field in Doctrine or Symfony?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to have some entities that have a `created` DateTime field, but I only want it to be settable when the entity is initially created but somehow define a rule that it can't be changed after the entity is created.

Is there any way to define this type of constraint either in Symfony constraints or Doctrine?

Comment: Why not check your logic instead? If you don't want to modify a field, simply don't change it in your application

Comment: you can't just  set the new datetime in the __construct?

Answer (score 0):

Typically, the way to achieve what you want is simply not to use a setter and to populate the field during entity instantiation.

```
class Foo

    private $number;
    private $createdAt;

    public __construct() {
        $this->createdAt = new DateTimeImmutable();
    }

    public getCreatedAt(): DateTimeImmutable {
        return $this->createdAt;
    }

    public setNumber(int $number) {
        $this->number = $number;
    }

    public getNumber(): int { return $this->int; }
}
```

This way you can know your entity will always have a valid `createdAt` field which won't depend on the DB or Doctrine, and since you do not have a setter you cannot modify the value from outside (without resorting to reflection or other tricks).

Comment: > since you do not have a setter you cannot modify the value from outside.  

Only if you use DateTimeImmutable instead of DateTime. :)
You can modify DateTime without setter, reflection and other tricks.

Answer (score 0):

It's not really a constraint.

You can do it like this

```
class Foo 
{
    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    private $createdAt;

    public __construct() {
        $this->createdAt = new DateTime();
    }

    public getCreatedAt(): DateTime {
        return $this->createdAt;
    }

    ...

}
```

By the way, have a look on Gedmo/Timestampable which provide you some stuff for your entities and mappings.
[StofDoctrine bundle](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle/index.html)
[Timestampable documentation](https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/v2.4.x/doc/timestampable.md)

Answer (score -2):

As a constraint no, but you can achieve this by using lifecycle callbacks. Check out [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/events.html#doctrine-lifecycle-callbacks)

Comment: My answer should not be downvoted, because it is a valid solution. Yes in the concrete case the accepted answer is better, but it’s not the “doctrine” way.